# Using Jquery with Radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm putting together a simple order lookup form. It worked well until I added radio buttons. In old JS, i used simple function to grab the radio button value and drop it into a string. Jquery does it a different way. I think I'm close to getting this working:

What I have so far:

> ```
> var e = $( "input:ordernum:checked" ).val(function( index, value) { 
>
> return value + " " + this.className;    
> var groupnum= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;    });
>
> xmlhttp.open("GET","ordersearch.php?orderid="+ordernum+"&q="+str,true);
> xmlhttp.send();
> ```

Previously, with the drop down, it used:

> ```
> var e = document.getElementById("groupnum");-->
>   var groupnum = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
>   });
> ```

It's probably a simple fix. Do I need getElementbyID or getElementbyName in this instance?

Comment: Nothing in your code after `return` will run. I don't even know what's for the `var groupnum`

Comment: May we see please your HTML for the radio buttons? It's not quite clear what string concatenation you need and how it's meant to be used later.

Comment: Also in the code you're showing us you have an *unuset* variable `ordernum`. Should it be instead `groupnum` ? Please fix your basics and show us more.

Answer (score 0):

```
var e = $( "input:ordernum:checked" ).val(function( index, value) {
```

I've no idea about a `:ordernum` selector in jQuery..

If you want to select an element using id, use `$('#id')` in your case,

`$('#ordernum:checked')`

But i don't think that's what you need ~ For creating a radio button group, give a common `name`  to all of them. Then you can access the value of selected radio button in the group like

`$('[name="yourGroupName"]:checked').val()`

Comment: "$('[name="yourGroupName"]:checked').val()" got it going. Have a lookup issue but the main tool is fixed. Thanks TJ. I knew it was just a newb problem.